# Brackets on Print Statements in Python on Stack Overflow

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

Why, in Python examples on Stack Overflow is there usually no brackets on 'print' statements? Is this because the version used is Python 2?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function

Comment: Yes, in those cases that there are no brackets it must be python 2

Comment: You're looking at old Python 2 code that uses the `print` statement. BTW, the `print` function can be enabled in several recent versions of Python 2 via `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: BTW, `()` are parentheses (singular: parenthesis). Brackets look like this: `[]`, although some people use the terms "square brackets" and "round brackets".

Comment: Unfortunately, some people use parentheses with `print` in Python 2 without having done the `__future__` import; so they're passing a tuple (or a single item) to the `print` statement, as discussed in the answers in the linked question. Code that's designed to run on both Python 2 & 3 should _always_ include the `__future__` import, and in fact should use this form to enable Python 3 division handling as well: `from __future__ import print_function, division`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print statement in Python 2 was removed in favor of a print function in Python3. Functions are invoked using parentheses - "()", so they are actually needed.